# Modify loading website html code with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a webpage I want to load, but I want to modify one of the scripts from that website. I simply want to change the code in from that website and then load the modified version. Is there a way of doing that without storing the page in a local file and then loading that? Maybe a Proxy?

Comment: What you ever tried?

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no experience with that. I never wrote a proxy and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I thought that maybe selenium delivers something like that out-of-the-box

Comment: But you know, here is SO. And however I can flag this question as **too broad**. So I think you should Google you question first, then try the solution that you found. If you got an error, then you can ask question here.

Comment: https://www.google.de/webhp?q=python+selenium+modify+http+response I found nothing useful. If this question is **too broad**, why don't you flag it as **too broad**?

Comment: selenium's document also nothing useful?

Comment: Because I have used all of my flags today...that isn't the important point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90106/discussion-between-distjubo-and-kevin-guan).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Proxies do work. You can use a proxy to modify the response of servers. You can simply tell selenium to use a proxy as follows:

```
PROXY = "127.0.0.1:4321"

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "socksProxy":None #You probably don't want this
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Simply replace `PROXY` with the desired proxy. And then, you have to start a Proxy on that port of the proxy. A few useful APIs are:
[Proxy-Tamper](https://github.com/tsyd/proxy-tamper)
[harmon](https://github.com/No9/harmon)
Or you can code one yourself, which is what I'm currently doing. Sample code to be added.

Comment: Congrats on finding an answer to your own question! :) I have done the same thing. Please make sure you come back and accept this answer once you can. Thanks.

Comment: I've found an even easier way for even easier purposes. https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-tamper fully serves my needs. Concept remains the same.

Comment: You should post that as an answer also so other people will be more likely to see it in the future... and then pick one and accept it.

Comment: This is not actually a complete answer to the question you asked. This is an answer to "How do I get Chrome to use a Proxy?" Your question was "How do I get Selenium to load a page whose code I altered." Using a proxy may be *part* of a solution but it is *just a part*.